# BokehJS BoxZoomTool always active by default, even when setting active: false

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

In BokehJS 2.4.2 the BoxZoomTool is always active by default, even when setting the `active` property to `false` when adding the tool.

```
const box_zoom = new Bokeh.BoxZoomTool({
    active: false,
});
plot.add_tools(box_zoom);
```

With other tools, such as the `FreehandDrawTool`, the tool is not active by default and the `active` property is not ignored.

How do you add the BoxZoomTool without being active by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BoxZoomTool has no parameter `active`, therefor the keyword is ignored in your example.

To set tools active, please check out this [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools).

In your case the line `p.toolbar.active_drag = None` does the trick, which deactivates all `pan/drag tools`, and you have only on off it.
This line accepts `"auto"`, `None` or an instance of `pan/drag`.

**Python Example**

```pythone
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import BoxZoomTool
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools='')
box_zoom = BoxZoomTool()
p.line(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,2,3,4,5])
p.toolbar.active_drag = None # could also be "auto" or box_zoom
p.add_tools(box_zoom)

show(p)
```

[image]

This can be adapted to JS.

Comment: Thanks (again) @mosc9575 for providing the solution. I have tried tried setting `p.toolbar.active_drag=null` before. However, as your solution explains, this should be set **before** `p.add_tools(box_zoom)`. When first adding the tool to the plot, setting the active drag tool to `null` does not deactivate the BoxZoomTool.